# how to use alternate port number to send mail

Tags: java

How to fix the exception

`Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25`

while sending email from java application and how to use alternate port number to send mail other than **port no:25** ?

Comment: Please show us the code that's trying to send the email.

Comment: And your code? how we know, where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to either find out which port that SMTP server is listening to OR find another host server that *is* listening on port 25.

There's no other way.  You're a supplicant, making a request.  If the host can't fulfill it, there's nothing you can do at your end to change that.

My advise is to find the SMTP host owner and ask how your client should contact them.  Make sure you have sufficient firewall rules and permissions to do so.